# FFmpeg blend mode is not working with `multiply` option

Tags: ffmpeg, blend

When using multiply blend option, the green color image is generated

Hi I'm using below code

```
ffmpeg -i gradient_0.png -i gradient_1.png -filter_complex "[0:v]setsar=1[v0];[1:v]setsar=1[v1];[v1][v0]blend=all_mode=multiply" output.jpeg -y
```

Input 1 with color code #eaeae9
[image: gradient_1]
Input 2 with color code #a9a499
[image: gradient_0]
Result with color code #3eda1e
[image: output]
But I need output like below image with color code #9b968c
[image]

Comment: Need ffmpeg ver >= 3.0

Comment: Hi Gyan the question is updated. Please give some solution